Why does Meziantou.Analyzer suggest to await GetManifestResourceStream?
Meziantou.Analyzer tells me to add an await in front of GetManifestResourceStream with info MA0042

Neither GetExecutingAssembly nor GetManifestResourceStream return a Task or Task<T>. So why can I await this call and what are possible reasons I should await it?
PS: I never had any problems with this code, I am just curious about the reasons

It does not tell you to await the stream. It suggests you prefer await using to using.

@GSerg you are right, it is because Stream is implementing IAsyncDisposable Thank you very much
